# Is there a way to make 0 values a different color in a MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting, matrix

I have a matrix plot that I create using the following code:

```
MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint,ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap",FrameTicks->{ticks,None,None,MapAt[Rotate[#,90 Degree]&,ticks,{All,2}]},PlotLegends->Automatic,RotateLabel->True,PlotLabel->Style[seqgroupname,FontSize->18]]
```

Since my data has many 0 values, I would like to show the 0 values as black to create a better contrast but I would like all other cells with values greater than 0 to use the "TemperatureMap" color function.  The reason I would like to do this is because as you can see in the picture below it is hard to distinguish between low values and 0 values.  How can I do this.

[image]

The code below works but it does not give a legend.  I am using version 11.3 Windows 10 64 bit.

```
outtabletoprint2={{1.0,0,0.015,0,0.0074,0,0.11,0.089,0.0074,0.0074,0,0.022},{0,1.0,0,0,0.0069,0,0.014,0.021,0,0,0.0069,0.0069},{0.0076,0.0076,1.0,0.015,0.046,0.015,0,0.038,0.015,0.015,0.015,0},{0,0,0.0081,1.0,0.0081,0,0,0.065,0,0,0.0081,0},{0,0.014,0,0,1.0,0,0,0.014,0,0,0.46,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1.0,0,0.023,0,0,0,0},{0.13,0,0.015,0,0.0075,0,1.0,0.69,0,0,0,0.22},{0.10,0,0.022,0,0.0075,0,0.67,1.0,0,0.015,0.015,0.14},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0071,1.0,0.19,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0071,0.21,1.0,0,0},{0,0.014,0,0,0.45,0,0,0.0070,0,0,1.0,0},{0.037,0,0.022,0,0.0075,0,0.23,0.17,0,0,0,1.0}};
seqgroupname2="Example"
indexnames2={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L};
(*This creates a variable to hold the tick mark names that define the categorical values of a heatmap*)
ticks2=Transpose[{Range[Length[indexnames2]],indexnames2}];

MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint2,ColorRules->{0->Black},ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap",FrameTicks->{ticks2,None,None,MapAt[Rotate[#,90 Degree]&,ticks2,{All,2}]},PlotLegends->Automatic,RotateLabel->True,PlotLabel->Style[seqgroupname2,FontSize->18]]
```

[image]

Comment: what do you get when you run `MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint2 /. 0 -> Black, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 FrameTicks -> {ticks2, None, None, 
   MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &, ticks2, {All, 2}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, RotateLabel -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[seqgroupname2, FontSize -> 18]]`?

Comment: An error that seems to amount to a problem with the datatype of the values in my array.  The first few are MatrixPlot[{{ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity, 
   Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity, 
   ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate, 
   ComplexInfinity}, {Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate, 
   Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity.........

Comment: In a worst case scenario you can try this `Show[MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint2, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  FrameTicks -> {ticks2, None, None, 
    MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &, ticks2, {All, 2}]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, RotateLabel -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[seqgroupname2, FontSize -> 18]], 
 MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint2, ColorRules -> {0 -> Black}, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]`

Comment: Better use string for indexnames2, i.e., indexnames2={"A",...}

Comment: I figured it out.  A straight Ctrl-C copy of @kglr Option #2 from one notebook to another results in the error.  However a Copy As-> Input text eliminates the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
outtabletoprint = RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {20, 20}];
```

**1.** You can replace `0`s in the input matrix with `Black`:

```
MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint /. 0 -> Black, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**2.** You can use the option `ColorRules`:

```
MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint, ColorRules -> {0 -> Black}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

> same picture

**Note:** Both methods work in version 9.0.1 (Windows 10 - 64 bit), in version 11.3 (Windows 10 -64 bit) and in version 12.1 (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: Option #1 did not work.  Option #2 works great except no legend is produced.  Do you have any idea why this would be.

Comment: @Jamie, both methods work in  version 9.0.1, in version 11.3 (Windows 10 -64bit) and in version 12.1 (Wolfram Cloud). Maybe your version/ OS is different. If so please add your version/OS info to your post.

Comment: Option #1 works.  The problem was with using Ctrl-C to copy code between notebooks.  Using Copy As->Input text fixed the error.  Thank you @kglr

Comment: @kglr your second solution does not produce Legend with  "12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)"

Answer (score 5):

```
color[z_] := Which[z == 0, Black, 0 < z <= 1, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[z, {0, 1}]]]

Legended[MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint2, ColorFunction -> color,  ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}]]
```

Or

```
MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint2, ColorFunction -> color, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

If you really want Yellow-Red color, you can use `SolarColors` in reverse order.

```
color[z_] := Which[z == 0, Black, 0 < z <= 1, ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}][Rescale[z, {0, 1}]]]

MatrixPlot[outtabletoprint2, ColorFunction -> color, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]